# PySpark : How to aggregate on a column with count of the different

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to aggregate on the `Identifiant` column with count of different `state` and represent all the `state`.

| Identifiant | state |
| --- | --- |
| ID01 | NY |
| ID02 | NY |
| ID01 | CA |
| ID03 | CA |
| ID01 | CA |
| ID03 | NY |
| ID01 | NY |
| ID01 | CA |
| ID01 | NY |

I'd like to obtain this dataset:

| Identifiant | NY | CA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID01 | 3 | 3 |
| ID02 | 1 | 0 |
| ID03 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `Identifiant` and pivot `State` column:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = (df.groupBy("Identifiant")
          .pivot("State")
          .count().na.fill(0)
          )

result.show()
#+-----------+---+---+
#|Identifiant| CA| NY|
#+-----------+---+---+
#|       ID03|  1|  1|
#|       ID01|  3|  3|
#|       ID02|  0|  1|
#+-----------+---+---+
```

Comment: Nice, but you can simplify the code: `df.groupby('Identifiant').pivot('State').count().fillna(0)`